# Risks of using a .NET Standard 1.3 Nuget in an application that targets .NET 4.6.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-standard

I have to say that I'm fairly new to .NET Standard.

I have the following issue:

I'm writing ASP.NET Web API 2 projects targetting the .NET 4.6.1 framework. When I install a nuget that targets .NET Standard 1.3, it pulls all its dependencies.

It seems fine ar first, the project compiles, but at runtime I have encountered many MethodNotFoundException(s).

To solve this issue, I had to unload the project to remove all these dependencies but the nuget library by hand. Then the project compiles and runs fine.

What Am I missing here ?

EDIT : I have had issue mostly with System.Net.Http.

Comment: Do you have any examples of specific packages that are consistently causing issues at runtime or is it all of the packages you've tried?

Comment: I'm only using the new Npgsql 3.2.0-Beta1 nuget, but I suspect it will break for all packages targetting .NET Standard 1.3.

Comment: Github issue with first analysis: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1405